# filter in objectdatasource in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

Hi i am using a gridview on my asp.net form . My problem is i want to given   filter option on the gridview. So how can i give the filter option as example user can filter data on `Orderdate` column of the gridview . I use to generate the object datasource for my application from `codesmith`

```
    <data:EntityGridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"
    DataSourceID="ActiveOrdersDataSource" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="OrderNo" AllowMultiColumnSorting="false"
    DefaultSortColumnName="OrderNo" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommond" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_OnRowDataBound"
    AllowSorting="true" DefaultSortDirection="Descending" ExcelExportFileName="Export_ActiveOrders.xls">
    <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderDate" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                        DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" HtmlEncode="False" HeaderText="Order Date" SortExpression="[OrderDate]" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="PickupCompanyName" HeaderText="Pickup Company" SortExpression="[PickupCompanyName]"
                                        Visible="false" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="DeliveryCompanyName" HeaderText="Delivery Company" SortExpression="[DeliveryCompanyName]"
                                        Visible="false" />
    </Columns>    
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
       <b>No Active Orders Found!</b>
     </EmptyDataTemplate>
 </data:EntityGridView>
```

Objectdatasource to bind the gridview

```
 <data:ActiveOrdersDataSource ID="ActiveOrdersDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetPaged" EnablePaging="True" EnableSorting="True" EnableDeepLoad="True">
<DeepLoadProperties Method="IncludeChildren" Recursive="False">
    <Types>
      <data:ActiveOrdersProperty Name="Clients" />
      <data:ActiveOrdersProperty Name="Companies" />
       <data:ActiveOrdersProperty Name="Drivers" />
       <data:ActiveOrdersProperty Name="SalesPeople" />
       <data:ActiveOrdersProperty Name="ServiceTypes" />
       <data:ActiveOrdersProperty Name="VehicleTypes" />
        <data:ActiveOrdersProperty Name="Zones" />

     </Types>
  </DeepLoadProperties>
    <Parameters>
 <data:CustomParameter Name="WhereClause" Value="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
 <data:CustomParameter Name="OrderByClause" Value="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
 <asp:ControlParameter Name="PageIndex" ControlID="GridView1" PropertyName="PageIndex" Type="Int32" />
 <asp:ControlParameter Name="PageSize" ControlID="GridView1" PropertyName="PageSize" Type="Int32" />
 <data:CustomParameter Name="RecordCount" Value="0" Type="Int32" />
  </Parameters>
</data:ActiveOrdersDataSource>
```